# Not getting data outside a function in JS

Tags: node.js

```
var content;

fs.readFile(file.path, 'utf8', function(err, data) {
  if ((path.extname(file.path)) == '.docx') {
    mammoth.extractRawText({
        path: file.path
      })
      .then(function(result) {
        content = result.value; // The raw text
        content = content.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm, "");
        console.log(content); // Printing this
      })
      .done();
  }
  console.log(content); //Not printing this
})
```

Why content not printing outside function even if the variable declared outside?

Comment: Due to async nature you cant get value like this

Comment: There were few mistakes in the code. I fixed them. Please check.

Comment: any way to get the value like this?

Comment: No, there's none! It's asynchronous code, so whatever value you set to the variable in the block is not available YET after the block. Try adding `console.log` statements in the code to see the order of execution yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using [waterfall](http://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#.waterfall) method of [async](http://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#) module

```
var async = require('async');
async.waterfall([function(next) {

  fs.readFile(file.path, 'utf8', function(err, data) {
    if ((path.extname(file.path)) == '.docx') {
      mammoth.extractRawText({
          path: file.path
        })
        .then(function(result) {
          content = result.value; // The raw text
          content = content.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm, "");
          console.log(content); // Printing this
          next(null,content)
        })
        .done();
    }
  })

}], function(err, content) {
  if (!err) {
    console.log(content);
  }
})
```